# Kubernetes volume map suggestion

Tags: kubernetes

I am using kubernetes as an orchestration tool for docker and have the below use case:

1. I have two containers say container-1 and container-2
2. I am exposing VOLUME (say /app/data) in container-1 image and would like to access this volume in container-2. This is very similar to --volumes-from in docker I am looking for.

How I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Containers are always on the same node?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes also has "Volumes", see here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/